# Select from table with clustered index and without has the same performance

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I'd liked to increase my knowledge about queries optimization and started from creating indexes.
Following some tutorial I created two tables: with and without cluster index on Primary Key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SuperHeroes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Class] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PowerLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NickName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CustomCodeAbilityId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SuperHeroes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SuperHeroes_NoIndex](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Class] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [PowerLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NickName] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CustomCodeAbilityId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I've inserted 498k rows to the table without the index PK and tried to do SELECT

```
select Id, [Class] ,[PowerLevel] ,[NickName] ,[Address] ,[CustomCodeAbilityId] FROM [test2].dbo.SuperHeroes_NoIndex
```

[image]
[image]

Then I copied all this records to the table with cluster index on PK and tried the same query:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the results are almost the same, what is strange to me as the query to the table with index should be much more quicker.

Even when I added sorting on column with PK the results increased a little but with the same value on both tables.

[image]
[image]

The question is: why I receive the same statistics for table with and without index?

**Update after replies:**

Thanks for all replies - they explained me a lot, but not everything.
When I added WHERE to select only one row:

- actual number of rows stay 498000 for table without index but       decreased to one on table with index - that's the improvements of       having index
- the same for estimated numbers - they decreased drasticly for table    without index
- there is even sugestion that from the db engine that I should add index :)

What I do not understand is the real time in Live Query Statistic tab - similar or even a little worse for table with index. Isn't that the core we fight for when optimizing?

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: index usually helps when looking up data, but when you select everything it doesn't matter as much. Try adding WHERE ID = 123

Comment: A clustered index is beneficial in several ways, but it isn’t going to make “select every column from every row” any faster. The main cost there is _reading all the data_, which is the same size regardless of an index. Indexes help by making more selective queries (specific columns, specific rows) _not_ have to read the whole table.

Comment: I recommend reading this article.  https://bertwagner.com/posts/clustered-vs-nonclustered-index-fundamentals-you-need-to-know/

Answer (score 1):

Indexes are not generally faster at being fully scanned than heap tables. Ultimately you are doing the same operation: scanning the whole table end-to-end (and all columns), and an index cannot speed that up in any way.

Where an index **is** beneficial is in being *seeked*: looking up the index for certain value(s) quickly. Whereas a heap would have to be fully scanned again, an index can jump to the right place.

[Think of the index like a phonebook:](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/10/how-to-think-like-the-sql-server-engine/) you can thumb through the tags to find the page starting with `Jones`. Whereas a heap is just that: a pile of pages.